# Random walk with multiple players

Tags: python

I am new to python and just had a class on random walks, but I am still confused on how to write code for them. I have been able to write a code for 1 player in the past, but I cannot figure out how to create a code for x amount of players.

The problem is: Every Player starts at position 1 and each turn every player flips a coin. The goal is to reach position n. If players flip heads, they move forward 1 step. If players flip tails they move backwards 1 step unless they are at position 1.

I have to write code that shows the number of turns required to reach the desired position n. So far I have this code, but it isn't working properly:

```
random.seed(123)
toss = 1000
walk= [0]

def bkkc(p,n):
    p=int(input('Enter number of players:'))
    n=int(input('Enter desired position:'))

while walk <= p:
    for coin_toss in range(toss):
        coin = random.randint (0,2)
        step = walk[coin_toss]
        if coin == 1:
            step += 1
        else:
            step = max(0, step -1)
    walk.append(step)

print(step)
```

Comment: Start by rewriting this code as some `def`s that capture the game phases. For instance, a `def setup(): ...` and a `def run_step(): ...`, and then a `def main(): setup(); while(!winner): run_step()` (with `winner` a True/False value that you set based on whether the goal was reached). Once you have that rewrite done, you now have code that works for a single player, and only requires changing the `run_step` function (plus a player list to track each player's current position) in order to make this a "more than one" player implementation.

Comment: I think you should think about in which data structure you can best store information about all players. A list does not seem adequate to me. You have to remember which player is in which position. A dictionary might be useful here.

Comment: You never call the function